# How to control android system rotation

Tags: android, rotation

I'm just making a test app that can control system rotation lock.

But I cannot find that kinds of documents related with my issue.

I'm wondering that I cannot find because I don't know what words to use to search or is the android didn't supply that kinds of function.

[what im talking to control that system rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6DRx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
}
or

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Thanks. But im sorry about i think that code is about controlling just applicatoin rotation.. im looking around for find to control system rotation

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.